# How to generate DDL for all Users and privileges in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I'm trying to migrate a database instance from RDS Oracle to On-premise Oracle. I'm still pretty new to database scripting. I found this script that does the work for me for a single user that I pass via SQLDeveloper. However I have 200+ users on my RDS Oracle instance.

https://oracle-base.com/dba/script?category=script_creation&file=user_ddl.sql

I have tried removing the variable here for the user name and the rownum but this generates a lot of duplicate entries. Can someone guide me what is the best way to achieve the result set of the above script for all users.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest another approach (if you can use it): data pump.

You'd perform export

- using user `SYSTEM` or `SYS` as they *own* the database and can export ...
- ... `FULL` database
- content would be `METADATA_ONLY` (so that you'd skip *data*; I understood you don't need that)

That would be something like

```
expdp system/pwd file=your_db.dmp full=y content=metadata_only
```

Import goes the same way, in the target database.

Comment: not sure if it will work with RDS Oracle. I'm figuring that out. Thank you for your response